# DFRO316 MCP3424 and STM32

Tags: stm32, device, arduino-uno, i2c, adc

I am trying to know the status of MCP3424, either it is connected or not to the master STM32 with defined address 0x68. The ADC module gets connected with the Arduino in same address but using STM32, I am not able to get connected with the following code:

while (1)
{
/* USER CODE END WHILE */

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
    if((HAL_I2C_IsDeviceReady(&hi2c1, 0x68 << 1, 100, 1000))==HAL_OK){
            HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, "device connected\r\n", 10, 10);
         }
    else{
      HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, "no device\r\n", 100, 10);
    }
```

}

Is there any mistake that I have done in this code by chance or any other way there is to deal with MCP3424 ADC module specifically? Please suggest me.

Comment: You might do better asking this on [arduino.se]

Comment: First of all, no, there is nothing special about it. 1) Arduino connects to it. 2) I2C is I2C.  Question: when you connect it to STM32, what is the voltage your I2C slave runs from?

Comment: I did a quick internet search, it may seem you don't need to shift the address to the left with that function. If that doesn't help, still, knowing voltage of I2C and voltage of A/D supply would help.

Comment: The ADC module is powered from the STM32 board with 4.98 V which is within the range as per datasheet suggests. I had checked other ADC module (ADS1115) with same configuration as well, all of them are being connected to STM32, just this module MCP3424 is not responding. However, it is working with Arduino well.

Comment: What's I2C voltage? Is I2C pulled up to 3.3V?

Comment: I checked, it was 0 V with STM32 and 4.68 V with Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem lies with voltage levels: your STM32 functions with 3.3V, while MCP3424 is powered from 5V. Let's open the datasheet of the MCP3424, page 6:

[image]

High level input voltage is 0.7Vdd, which is 0.7V*5V=3.5V, which means your A/D can't detect "1" on the line. It sees the line as always "0", even when STM32 MCU outputs HIGH (3.3V).

Possible solutions:

1. Logic level conversion (various ways). A circuit between A/D IC and MCU to convert 3.3V levels into 5V levels. There are dedicated chips for that, there are also other approaches using resistors and mosfets. Something you may want to explore on electrical engineering stackexchange.
2. Check the datasheet of the MCU, find GPIO properties. It's very likely those I2C pins are in fact 5V-tolerant, meaning you can pull up I2C lines to 5V and still drive them with 3.3V STM32, and it will be within the spec of STM32 MCU. If that's the case, no extra circuit will be necessary.

Comment: Thank you @IIya. No need to use extra circuit as STM32 can itself pull up I2C lines to required voltage, just need to manually pull up it through software.

Comment: @PrashantWaiba no, you can't. STM32 can only pull up to 3.3V, because STM32 MCU runs on 3.3V. You need to pull up to 5V. That's exactly the problem. You need to externally pull up to 5V, but if and only if those STM32 pins are 5V-tolerant = won't burn from 5V (which is explicitly stated in datasheet about every pin)